# Loading content in through jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

If you look at the screenshot in the below link you'll see what I'm after. I basically want people to be able to click a service down the left hand side and then the content loads in on the right hand side. Like [this page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AJAXReplaceSamePart/) but instead of loading below, it loads to the right, and also, the link there loads the content in via a html file, I'd like to avoid this is possible.

Screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin or ajax that can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you looking to understand how to implement such a thing, or do you just want some code you can copy and paste?

Comment: have a look at jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, specifically [loading page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jquery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for that.
Or alternatively preload all the contents and use [jquery UI's tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: I owe you a massive beer!